# Extract text from a multiline string using Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a string that covers several lines. I need to extract the text between two strings. For example:

```
Start Here Some example
text covering a few
lines. End Here
```

I need to extract the string, `Start Here Some example text covering a few lines.`

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
print $1 if /(Start Here.*?)End Here/s;
```

Answer (score 38):

Use the `/s` regex modifier to treat the [string as a single line](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers):

> /s
>   Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

```
  $string =~ /(Start Here.*)End Here/s;
  print $1;
```

This will capture up to the *last* `End Here`, in case it appears more than once in your text.

If this is not what you want, then you can use:

```
  $string =~ /(Start Here.*?)End Here/s;
  print $1;
```

This will stop matching at the very first occurrence of `End Here`.

Comment: You're also using the greedy match, so if someone has something that says... "start blah blah end blah blah start blah blah end", it will capture both start/end sequences.  If you use `.*?` instead, you'll limit yourself to one match at a time.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `echo -e "test1\ntest2" > test && perl -ne 'print $_ if /test1.*test2/s' test` prints nothing.

Comment: @Hi-Angel That's a different related question about using the `-n` flag, which is mostly answered at [Perl command line multi-line replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671078) --- *(however if it isn't, it should be asked in a new question)*

Comment: @user202729 thanks for clearing up confusion, I just tried it, works for me. Upshot though: it seems perl's "treat all text as a single line" interface has a limited usefulness, because it either matches the whole text, or a single match of a group. For example: `echo -e "test1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest1\ntest2" > test && perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /(test1\ntest2)/' test` gives "test1\ntest2" output just once. Using `^` and `$` is also not possible. I'll see if I find time to report a feature request for proper multiline support, kind of like Emacs regexes do.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't the correct modifier to treat the string as a single line be (?s) rather than (/s) ?  I've been wrestling with a similar problem for quite a while now and the RegExp Tester embedded in JMeter's View Results Tree listener shows my regular expression extractor with the regex

```
(?s)<FMSFlightPlan>(.*?)</FMSFlightPlan>
```

matches

```
<FMSFlightPlan>
C87D
AN NTEST/GL 
- FPN/FN/RP:DA:GCRR:AA:EIKN:F:SAMAR,N30540W014249.UN873. 
BAROK,N35580W010014..PESUL,N40529W008069..RELVA,N41512W008359.. 
SIVIR,N46000W008450..EMPER,N49000W009000..CON,N53545W008492 
</FMSFlightPlan>
```

while the regex

```
(?s)<FMSFlightPlan>(.*?)</FMSFlightPlan>
```

does not match. Other regex testers show the same result. However when I try to execute a the script I get the Beanshell Assertion error:

> Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*;  //write out the data results to a file outfile = "/Users/Dani . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 12, column 380.  Encountered: "\n" (10),

So something else is definitely wrong with mine. Anyway, just a suggestion

Comment: The two regexes you mentioned are identical: "`(?s)<FMSFlightPlan>(.*?)</FMSFlightPlan>`"... Is there maybe a typo in the second one?