# How can I match multi-line patterns in the command line with perl-style regex?

Tags: regex, perl, multiline, command-line-tool

I regularly use regex to transform text.

To transform, giant text files from the command line, perl lets me do this:

```
perl -pe < in.txt > out.txt
```

But this is inherently on a line-by-line basis. Occasionally, I want to match on multi-line things.

How can I do this in the command-line?

Comment: I am sure Perl can do what you need. You can ask it to use a record separator other than newline, or it can split the file at blank lines or using a fixed record size. Or, if your file is a reasonable size, you can read it all into memory and work on it from there. I can't tell what would be the best approach unless you explain more about your application

Comment: see http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch06_01.htm

Comment: Specifically, `perl -0777 -pe ...` is not inherently on a line-by-line basis. :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl command line multi-line replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670426/perl-command-line-multi-line-replace)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To slurp a file instead of doing line by line processing, use the `-0777` switch:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/.../.../g' in.txt > out.txt
```

As documented in [`perlrun #Command Switches`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches):

> The special value `-00` will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode. Any value `-0400` or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value `-0777` is the one normally used for this purpose.

Obviously, for large files this may not work well, in which case you'll need to code some type of buffer to do this replacement.  We can't advise any better though without real information about your intent.

Answer (score 1):

**Grepping across line boundaries**

So you want to grep across lines boundaries...

You quite possibly already have `pcregrep` installed. As you may know, PCRE stands for `Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions`, and the library is definitely Perl-style, though not identical to Perl.

To match across multiple lines, you have to turn on the multi-line mode `-M`, which is not the same as `(?m)`

Running `pcregrep -M "(?s)^b.*\d+" text.txt`

On this text file:

```
a
b
c11
```

The output will be

```
b
c11
```

whereas grep would return empty.

**Excerpt from the doc:**

> -M, --multiline Allow patterns to match more than one line. When this  option is given, patterns may usefully contain literal newline char-
>   acters and internal occurrences of ^ and  $  characters.  The output 
>   for  a  successful match may consist of more than one line, the last
>   of which is the one in which the match  ended. If the matched string
>   ends with a newline sequence the output ends at the end of that line.
>
> When this option is set, the PCRE library is called in  "mul- tiline" 
>   mode.   There is a limit to the number of lines that can be matched,
>   imposed by the way that pcregrep buffers  the input  file as it scans
>   it. However, pcregrep ensures that at least 8K characters or the rest
>   of the document (whichever is the  shorter)  are  available for
>   forward matching, and simi- larly the previous 8K characters (or all
>   the previous charac- ters,  if  fewer  than 8K) are guaranteed to be
>   available for lookbehind assertions. This option does not work  when 
>   input is read line by line (see --line-buffered.)

Comment: That sounds about like what I want, except I also need the substitution part as well.