# Perl regex start of line anchor fails

Tags: regex, perl

I want to change the 'this' on the second row of the example, but it's not happening.  Most grateful for an idea where I'm going wrong.

```
echo "not this but
this one" > test.txt
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^this/rhinoceros/igs' test.txt
cat test.txt
not this but
this one
```

Comment: What `-0777` does? Do you need it?

Comment: [This explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9671078/1156245).  I'm not sure what 'slurping' means.  You're right though removing it does fix the problem.

Comment: Slurping is reading a whole file at once, and it seems like you want to read the file one line at the time (ie. get rid of that parameter).

Comment: @geotheory: You mustn't just write things because you've seen them elsewhere, without having any idea what they're doing. Also, your question needs specifying a lot better. Do you want to replace `this` only on the second line of a file, only the first time it appears at the start of a line, *every time* it appears at the start of a line, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have all the wrong modifiers on your substitution. You presumably only want to make a single change, so the `/g` is unnecessary; the text to be matched is exactly `this`, so the `/i` is unnecessary, and you have no dot `.` characters in your pattern, so `/s` doesn't do anything

What you *do* need is a `/m` (multi-line) modifier so that the `^` matches the beginning of lines in the middle of the string, as well as just at the start of the string

This should work for you

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^this/rhinoceros/m' test.txt
```

Comment: Simpler: `perl -i -pe 's/^this/rhinoceros/' test.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the /s flag, you actually want the /m flag.

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^this/rhinoceros/igm' test.txt
```

`s` treats the whole string as a single line, whereas `m` matches over multiple lines.

**Edit:** See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for a more detailed treatment of the `s` and `m` modifiers that @ThisSuitIsBlackNot comments on below. For practical purposes, `s` "treat[s] string as single line".

Comment: Thanks!  Do you happen to know what `-0777` is doing - i.e. what is ['slurping'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9671078/1156245)?

Comment: As @Сухой27 mentioned it's reading a whole file into memory at once rather than iterating over it line by line. Not sure exactly what your end state is, but you'd need to slurp the file to do your multi-line substitution in a one-shot command line like that.

Comment: `s` does not treat the whole string as a single line, it causes `.` to match any character including newlines. `m` causes `^` and `$` to match at the start or end of any line anywhere within the string, not just the beginning or end of the entire string.

Comment: Okay, "in effect" tells Perl to pretend the string is a single line.

Comment: Thanks guys that's helpful