# Perl regexs: replace a run of spaces and newlines

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace, removing-whitespace

File `bar`'s whitespace consists only of spaces and newlines:

```
$ cat bar
1, 2,
  3,
4
```

I want to replace consecutive runs of whitespace (spaces and newlines) with `S`, i.e. desired output is:

```
1,S2,S3,S4S
```

However, all my attempts result in `\n` being replaced by one `S`, and spaces that immediately follow it replaced by another `S`:

```
$ cat bar | perl -pe 's/\s+/S/g'
1,S2,SS3,S4S
$ cat bar | perl -pe 's/\s+/S/gm'
1,S2,SS3,S4S
$ cat bar | perl -pe 's/\s+/S/gms'
1,S2,SS3,S4S
$ cat bar | perl -pe 's/[ \n]+/S/gms'
1,S2,SS3,S4S
$ cat bar | perl -pe 's/[ \n]+/S/gm'
1,S2,SS3,S4S
$ cat bar | perl -pe 's/[ \n]+/S/g'
1,S2,SS3,S4S
```

These are all the combinations of relevant regex flags I can think of: `/g` (global substitution), `/s` (let `.` match newlines), and `/m` (multi-line); I always have `SS` preceding the `3`, where I want just `S`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl -p` reads the input line by line. You need to read the whole input at once, or remember whether the previous line ended in whitespace.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\s+/S/g'
```

`-0777` reads the whole file at once.

```
perl -pe 's/^\s+// unless 1 == $.; s/\s+/S/g;'
```

Here, any leading whitespace is removed (except for the first line). We know it must be preceded by a newline, anyway.

Comment: as a follow-on, wouldn't `-0` work just as well as `-0777`? It seems to for my example here.

I see discussion [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=269283) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9671078/544236) about it, with possible implications for unicode handling, but can't tell why one or the other might make more sense.

Comment: @RyanWilliams `-0` works as long as the input doesn't contain any null bytes, so it's okay in this case. `-0777` is better because it will always slurp the entire file regardless of what characters are in the input. Also, `-0777` means "slurp" by convention, so experienced Perl programmers can understand what you're doing at a glance without having to wonder if you're intentionally splitting on null bytes.