# Replace newline in quoted strings in huge files

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a few huge files with values seperated by a pipe (|) sign.
The strings our quoted but sometimes there is a newline in between the quoted string.

I need to read these files with external table from oracle but on the newlines he will give me errors. So I need to replace them with a space.

I do some other perl commands on these files for other errors, so I would like to have a solution in a one line perl command.

I 've found some other similar questions on stackoverflow, but they don't quite do the same and I can't find a solution for my problem with the solution mentioned there.

The statement I tried but that isn't working:

```
perl -pi -e 's/"(^|)*\n(^|)*"/ /g' test.txt
```

Sample text:

```
4454|"test string"|20-05-1999|"test 2nd string"
4455|"test newline
in string"||"test another 2nd string"
4456|"another string"|19-03-2021|"here also a newline
"
4457|.....
```

Should become:

```
4454|"test string"|20-05-1999|"test 2nd string"
4455|"test newline in string"||"test another 2nd string"
4456|"another string"|19-03-2021|"here also a newline "
4457|.....
```

Comment: You are reading a line at at time. The pattern can't possible match since you require it to match characters after the end of the line. The simple solution it to tell Perl to treat the entire file as one line by using `-0777`. This may be an issue for you ("huge files").

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I added a sample

Comment: @ikegami: Could you give me the one line clause then to treat the file in it's whole ?

Comment: Maybe `perl -pi -e 's/(\r?\n)(?!\d{4,}\|)/ /g' test.txt` (skipping those followed by a number)

Comment: Or `perl -0777 -pi -e 's/\R++(?!\d{4,}\|)/ /g' file`

Comment: Note that it's possible to import a csv file with oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, you can also consider a workaround using GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk).

An [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command will look like

```sh
awk 'NR==1 {print;next;} /^[0-9]{4,}\|/{print "\n" $0;next;}1' ORS="" file > newfile
```

The ORS (output record separator) is set to an empty string, which means that `\n` is only added before lines starting with four or more digits followed with a `|` char (matched with a `^[0-9]{4,}\|` POSIX ERE pattern).

A GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command will look like

```sh
sed -i ':a;$!{N;/\n[0-9]\{4,\}|/!{s/\n/ /;ba}};P;D' file
```

This reads two consecutive lines into the pattern space, and once the second line doesn't start with four digits followed with a `|` char (see the `[0-9]\{4\}|` POSIX BRE regex pattern), the or more line break between the two is replaced with a space. The search and replace repeats until no match or the end of file.

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), if the file is huge **but it can still fit into memory**, you can use a short

```sh
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/\R++(?!\d{4,}\|)/ /g'  <<< "$s"
```

With `-0777`, you [slurp the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671078/3832970) and the `\R++(?!\d{4,}\|)` pattern matches any one or more line breaks (`\R++`) not followed with four or more digits followed with a `|` char. The `++` possessive quantifier is required to make `(?!...)` negative lookahead to disallow backtracking into line break matching pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want a CSV parser like [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) (Install through your OS's package manager or favorite CPAN client):

```sh
$ perl -MText::CSV_XS -e '
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({sep => "|", binary => 1});
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
  $csv->say(*STDOUT, [ map { tr/\n/ /r } @$row ]) 
}' test.txt
4454|"test string"|20-05-1999|"test 2nd string"
4455|"test newline in string"||"test another 2nd string"
4456|"another string"|19-03-2021|"here also a newline "
```

This one-liner reads each record using `|` as the field separator instead of the normal comma, and for each field, replaces newlines with spaces, and then prints out the transformed record.

Comment: Exactly this. (Well, I'd go with `tr/\n/ / for @$row; $csv->say(*STDOUT, $row);` But the time savings it gives aren't that big.) I'd upvote twice if I could.

Comment: And exactly the same here :)  A _perfect_ example of the utility of that library

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, this could be simply done in `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`. This should work fast even on huge files(better than slurping whole file into memory, having mentioned that OP may use it on huge files).

```
awk 'gsub(/"/,"&")%2!=0{if(val==""){val=$0} else{print val $0;val=""};next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
gsub(/"/,"&")%2!=0{                  ##Checking condition if number of " are EVEN or not, because if they are NOT even then it means they are NOT closed properly.
  if(val==""){ val=$0            }   ##Checking condition if val is NULL then set val to current line.
  else       {print val $0;val=""}   ##Else(if val NOT NULL) then print val current line and nullify val here.
  next                               ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
1                                    ##In case number of " are EVEN in any line it will skip above condition(gusb one) and simply print the line.
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```