# Regextract Google Spreadsheet - Extract text from multiline string

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have the same issue of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764350/extract-text-from-a-multiline-string-using-perl)

but I'm using Google Spreadsheet. Even though it's not considered a "programming" topic, regex syntax it be the same.

I need to extract text between two tags. Eg:

```
START sample text END
```

When I apply this regex syntax everything works:

```
"START(.*)END"
```

But if the sample text contains a new line it does not. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get rid off the new line character, one solution would be to replace the new line character with "", e.g:

```
=regexextract(regexreplace(A1, "\n", ""), "START (.+) END")
```

If you want to keep the new line character, you could try:

```
=regexextract(A1, "START (\w+\n\w+) END")
```

Alternatively if you want a solution that works with strings WITH and WITHOUT new line character, try:

```
=regexextract(A1, "START (\w+|\w+\n\w+) END")
```

Comment: Thanks it works! How can I prevent now to get an extracted text with a single line?

Comment: Hi Daniele, I assumed you didn't want the result to have the new line. I edited my answer. See if it works for you ?