# Extracting field from multiline text that is piped into Perl

Tags: regex, postgresql, perl

I would like to extract a number (`7`, in this example) from input of the following kind:

```
 received_tli 
--------------
            7
(1 row)
```

I've seen [recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764350/extract-text-from-a-multiline-string-using-perl) for the case where the multi-line string exists as a Perl variable. However, I would prefer invoking the expression like this:

```
psql -c "SELECT received_tli FROM pg_stat_wal_receiver" | \
  perl -e 'print $1 if /<expression>/'
```

I've tried e.g. `\s^received_tli\s*\n-+\n\s*([0-9])+\s*\n(1 row)` as expression, but this does not seem to work. How can I parse multiline input that is piped into Perl with a (multiline) regular expression?

Comment: Surely you want to print out every line that isn't the header or row count and you don't need a multiline regular expression for that

Comment: It would be better to write this whole thing in Perl using the DBI module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having with your `perl -e` is that at no point are you reading `STDIN`, and thus perl isn't 'seeing' your data.

You can use `-ne` which tells perl to wrap your snippet in a `while ( <> ) { }` loop. That's maybe of limited use though, because it's working line by line.

So then you need to set the 'end of line delimiter' (`-0` flag) and then apply your regex:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if m/received_tli\D*(\d+)/'
```

Or written in a longer perl script (but hopefully more readable):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
while (<>) {
   print $1,"\n" if m/received_tli\D*(\d+)/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to involve Perl at all. Just use the `-t` or `--tuples-only` option in `psql`:

```
psql -t -c "SELECT received_tli FROM pg_stat_wal_receiver"
```

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data, it looks like you want the integer on lines that only contain that integer and some white space. So something like this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  /^\s*(\d+)\s*$/ and print $1;
}
```

You can put that in a file, make it executable and then run it using:

```
$ psql ... | your_extract_program
```

But if you really want to retype the Perl code every time, you could use:

```
$ psql ... | perl -n -e 'print $1 if /^\s*(\d+)\s*$/'
```